# Can't display table in SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE table employee
(employee_id int,
firstName varchar(20),
lastName varchar(20),
jobTitle varchar(30),
title varchar(10),
age varchar(10),
address varchar(30),
salary varchar(20)
);

insert into employee values('1', 'Jonnie', 'Weber', 'Secretary', '28', 'Randburg', '19500.00');
insert into employee values('2', 'Patsy', 'Weber','Programmer','32','NorthCliff','455300.00');
insert into employee values('3','Dirk','Smith','Programmer II','45','Sandton','75020.00');


select * from employee;
```

I got a yellow line under de * so I can't exactly display my table, what does this mistake means?

Comment: Do you actually get an error when you run this? (Also, don't store numbers as strings; or string literals for number values; and use varchar2 not varchar for columns that are actually strings.)

Answer (score 1):

It is just a warning stating not to use wildcards to select columns. Always use explicit column names to select.